# Why doesn't jsTree plugin drag and drop always work?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jstree, jstree-dnd

I'm using the great [JSTree jQuery plugin](https://www.jstree.com/plugins/) and have configured it to use the 'dnd' (drag and drop plugin), and it is working properly. However, half of the time I try to drag a file into a folder, it does not work. It shows the green check mark as if I am allowed to, but after I complete the drop (release the mouse), the file doesn't always actually get added into the folder until I try again another time or two (or sometimes it just works on the first time).

Is there a known fix for this? Digging around I found an older post about this very issue, but that was with the older version of jsTree which uses [marker lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081146/jstree-drag-and-drop-is-not-always-working) in between each node, but the newer version I am using doesn't have the "#jstree-marker-line" element anywhere to be found.